# Send message alert to multiple computers on a network

Tags: networking, message

I have a really simple question. I was at school today and someone had managed to send a message alert saying 'hello' to every computer in the library. It took a while for the messages to go away, no-one could get rid of it. I don't want to do what they did, but I am interested in how they did it. I'm studying computer science as a major at my school.

Answer (score 0):

> Linux_User:~$ echo "message" | wall